# can't find OpenCV package on RHEL 8

Tags: opencv, yum, rhel

Some sites say OpenCV could be installed on RHEL from the system repository:

```
sudo yum install opencv opencv-devel opencv-python
```

I run RHEL UBI container `redhat/ubi8` and tried to install OpenCV - package is not found.
Then I install EPEL repos from `https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm`, same result. The only opencv-related package is `libfreenect-opencv`.

I understand I could compile OpenCV from the scratch, but I'd like to go with already compiled package.

Comment: if you just need it from python, just `pip install opencv-contrib-python`

Comment: voting to close because this isn't a _programming_ issue, it's a sysop/sysadmin/server config issue and should be a better fit on https://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable CodeReady Linux Builder Repository on RHEL 8:

```bash
subscription-manager repos --enable codeready-builder-for-rhel-8-x86_64-rpms
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I do not have RHEL subscription.
Is there a way to install opencv without the subscription?